# array processing from googlesheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-sheets

i have a googlesheet and i want to process it as an object in javascript.
the googlesheet has 6 columns and multiple rows. my axios request to the googlesheet returns each cell of the sheet as an object and I need to set each 6 cells as one object. the result is like this...

[

{ row: '1', col: '1', name: 'name' },                                                                          { row: '1', col: '2', name: 'lastname' },                                                                    { {row: '1', col: '3', name: 'age' },                                                                            { row: '1', col: '4', name: 'birthday' },                                                                  { row: '1', col: '5', name: 'score' },                                                                     { row: '1', col: '6', name: 'salary' },                                                                         { row: '2', col: '1', name: 'Aklilu' },                                                                       { row: '2', col: '2', name: 'Berihun' },                                                                  { {row: '2', col: '3', name: '20' },                                                                            { row: '2', col: '4', name: '1/8/2020' },

]...

so what I am tryig to get is an array of objects that has every 6 cells as a single object of the properties
{
name:
lastname:
age:
birthday:
score:
salary:
}

which are the first row of the sheet...

please help.

Comment: Looks like there is an extra bracket before each `col: 3` object `{ {row: '1', col: '3', name: 'age' }`. Is that a typo in your question, or the retrieved data has this format? That doesn't look like a valid object format.